# special char Android (ø)

Tags: java, android, char

i have to retrieve some data from a txt file and then show those data inside my app.

My problem is that if i have the special char 'ø' inside my txt, this is not shown and a '?' is shown instead.

i tried to check data like

```
 if(string.charAt(i) == 'ø') do sth
```

or

```
string.replace('ø' , 'O')
```

but none of them is working and i think that Java could not recognize that char at all.

Do you have any idea?

thanks

**edit**

this is how i read data

```
String[] obj = getText(getActivity(), myTXT.txt").split("\n");
```

where getText is:

```
    public String getText(Context c, String fileName){

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {

        AssetManager am = c.getAssets();
        InputStream is = am.open(fileName); 

        outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = is.read(buf)) != -1){
            outputStream.write(buf,0,len);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        is.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return outputStream.toString();
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that you are using to read from the file.

Answer (score 0):

These chars must be in `UTF-8` encoding, check for your file while its getting saved whether its incoding. Create an `InputStreamReader` instance that uses the constructor specifying encoding.

```
InputStreamReader r= new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(myFile),"UTF-8");
// read your contents here.
r.close();
```